# PHP loop to read from SQLite and write to arrays/JSON

Tags: php, json, loops, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 database which contains 4 tables with 9 rows each.
I've tried to do each one of the arrays one-by-one, with basically the same code as below (everything in the foreach loop), and it worked fine. I guess I just made some stupid mistakes (I don't really use PHP, this is pretty much the only project I've used it in). I tried to fix it, but somehow PHP is not really friendly today. 
Currently the code below returns a JSON with 4 empty arrays.

```
<?php 
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $db = new PDO('sqlite:whad.db')or die('Could not open database');

$arDaniel = array();
$arAndi = array();
$arDave = array();
$arSimon = array();

for ($j=0; $j < 4; $j++) { 
  $name;
  $arr;

  if (j == 0) {
    $name = 'Daniel';
    $arr = $arDaniel;
  }
  elseif (j == 1) {
    $name = 'Andi';
    $arr = $arAndi;
  }
  elseif (j == 2) {
    $name = 'Dave';
    $arr = $arDave;
  }
  elseif (j == 3) {
    $name = 'Simon';
    $arr = $arSimon;
  }

  $query = "SELECT Datum, ID, RR, RL, KB, BD, SD, KH, Reihenfolge FROM $name ORDER BY date(Datum)";
  $i = 1;
  foreach($res = $db->query($query) as $value) {
    $curr = array();
    array_push($curr["Datum"] = $value[0]);
    array_push($curr["ID"] = $value[1]);
    array_push($curr["RR"] = $value[2]);
    array_push($curr["RL"] = $value[3]);
    array_push($curr["KB"] = $value[4]);
    array_push($curr["BD"] = $value[5]);
    array_push($curr["SD"] = $value[6]);
    array_push($curr["KH"] = $value[7]);
    array_push($curr["Reihenfolge"] = $value[8]);
    array_push($arr[$i] = $curr);
    $i++;
  }
}
$json = array(
    "Daniel" => $arDaniel,
    "Andi" => $arAndi,
    "Dave" => $arDave,
    "Simon" => $arSimon
  );

echo json_encode($json);

$db = NULL;
?>
```

EDIT: Removed quotes around $curr.

Comment: What is this line `array_push($arr[$i] = "$curr");` really doing?

Comment: First, I put the SQLite data of a row in the array $curr. After that, I put it in one of the 4 arrays ($arDaniel, $arAndi, $arDave, $arSimon; Which are basically the tables of the database). So I return one JSON with 4 nested objects. One for each array. In each array the entries are labeled from 1-n, n being the amount of columns in the database.

Comment: Oh, but the qutes shouldn't be around $curr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many unnecassary variables with the same data.
You simply could do the following

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$db = new PDO('sqlite:whad.db')or die('Could not open database');

$json = array(
  "Daniel" => array(),
  "Andi" => array(),
  "Dave" => array(),
  "Simon" => array()
);

foreach($json as $name => &$arr){
  $query = "SELECT Datum, ID, RR, RL, KB, BD, SD, KH, Reihenfolge FROM $name ORDER BY date(Datum)";

  $stmt = $db->query($query);
  //now comes the trick, that you tell pdo to fecth them already as array
  $arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

unset($arr);


echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Look at the first example here: http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Also note the & before $arr, which will handle the $arr variable as reference (also the unset, because after the last pass, it would still be set, this is just good style to clean up)

**Update:**
As in the other answer you have to use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC to get an array with only the index names.

Comment: I just fixed my version (forgot the "$" in the if statements), but your version is way easier on the eyes. However, when I use it, it returns all my data twice. One time numberes 1-n, and directly below (in the same JSON nest layer) with the row labels. Is it possible to only send the one with the labels?

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one error in your code:

```
$arDaniel = array();
$arAndi = array();
$arDave = array();
$arSimon = array();

for ($j=0; $j < 4; $j++) { 
    $name;                                              # <---
    $arr;                                               # <---
```

This sort of ‘declaration’ in php is unnecessary, you can remove `$name` and `$arr` (it's not an error, btw);

```
    if (j == 0) {                                       # <---
```

In the `for` loop you use `$j`, you can't use `j` here: replace it with `$j` (in php variables are ever prepended by `$`);

```
        $name = 'Daniel';
        $arr = $arDaniel;                               # <---
```

By this assignment, you want change the original array, but with this assignment *by value*, you in fact create a copy of `$arDaniel`, and new elements are added only to `$arr`, not to `$arDaniel`; to do this, you have to do an assignment *by reference* through `&` keyword: replace this (and following similar) line with `$arr = &$arDaniel;`

```
    }
        elseif (j == 1) {                               # <--- see above
        $name = 'Andi';
        $arr = $arAndi;                                 # <--- see above
    }
        elseif (j == 2) {                               # <--- see above
        $name = 'Dave';
        $arr = $arDave;                                 # <--- see above
    }
        elseif (j == 3) {                               # <--- see above
        $name = 'Simon';
        $arr = $arSimon;                                # <--- see above
    }
    $query = "SELECT Datum, ID, RR, RL, KB, BD, SD, KH, Reihenfolge FROM $name ORDER BY date(Datum)";
    $i = 1;                                             # <---
```

The query is formally correct, but I don't know your table structure. `$i = 1;` is unnecessary (see below);

```
    foreach($res = $db->query($query) as $value) {
        $curr = array();
        array_push($curr["Datum"] = $value[0]);         # <---
        array_push($curr["ID"] = $value[1]);            # <---
        array_push($curr["RR"] = $value[2]);            # <---
        array_push($curr["RL"] = $value[3]);            # <---
        array_push($curr["KB"] = $value[4]);            # <---
        array_push($curr["BD"] = $value[5]);            # <---
        array_push($curr["SD"] = $value[6]);            # <---
        array_push($curr["KH"] = $value[7]);            # <---
        array_push($curr["Reihenfolge"] = $value[8]);   # <---
        array_push($arr[$i] = $curr);                   # <---
        $i++;                                           # <---
    }
}
```

The `array_push` syntax is not correct (see [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)): the correct syntax is `array_push( $existentArray, $newElement )`. In addition, you can't use `array_push` to add an associative value, you can use it only for numeric key. Change `$curr` assignments simply in `$curr['Datum'] = $value[0];` etc...

To append `$curr` to `$arr`, you have to change the line in `array_push( $arr, $curr )` or (better, as php recommends if only one element is appended) `$arr[] = $curr;`. After these changes, the `$i++;` line can be deleted.

```
$json = array(
    "Daniel" => $arDaniel,
    "Andi" => $arAndi,
    "Dave" => $arDave,
    "Simon" => $arSimon
);

echo json_encode($json);

$db = NULL;
```

Now your script is clean (I hope).

Your script remain a bit redundant. You can simplify it in this way:

```
$array = array( 'Daniel'=>array(), 'Andi'=>array(), 'Dave'=>array(), 'Simon'=>array() );
foreach( $array as $key => &$val )
{
    $query = "SELECT Datum, ID, RR, RL, KB, BD, SD, KH, Reihenfolge FROM $key ORDER BY date(Datum)";

    $result = $db->query( $query );
    $val    = $result->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}

$json = json_encode( $array );
echo $json;
```

By this way, you init an array with names as key, then, in a `foreach` loop *by reference* (`&$val`) you perform a sql query searching in table `$key` and you fetch all results directly in array (in this example the values are stored as associative arrays, like in your example, but you can use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` to store data as object). At the end, you encode the array end echo it.

#### Edit:

I see a previous answer nearly identical to mine...
BTW, I leave mine because I have spent a lot of time to explain various errors...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and explaining my errors! I had already fixed a couple of those, and it worked (well, slow, but it did), but yours and Fabian's is a lot easier to read and faster. Thank both of you!